# partitioning alongside Windows 7

Tags: partitioning

I am attempting to install ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7. I am not advanced in linux so I am a little confused. Whenever I attempt to install ubuntu from the CD, I get all the way to the point where it asks me to partition my drive. On the basic level there is a 2 sided bar that can be dragged back and forth to select how many GB you wish. My question is: Which side of the 2 bars is the ubuntu side, and which side is the Windows 7 side? There is no way to differentiate between the 2 bars. I suspect the ubuntu side is the right side, because its default setting is a lower GB amount than the left side; but I can't be sure, and I do not want to screw up my windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, normally Ubuntu should be at the smaller side. However it normally shows the OS so that you can differentiate.